# Add local branch to remote repository?

Tags: repository, git

In git, I created a new local branch and made various changes that have been committed.  I'd like to now add this branch to the remote repository (not local `master` branch or `origin/master` remote branch.)  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was able to create it like this:

```
git push origin BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Yup, that's it :)